# telerik griddataitem, visible set to false

Tags: telerik

We are using `Telerik` to display contents of a db.

Is there a way to make `GridDataItem` be omitted when page is rendered? We could set attribute visible to `false` which makes row not show up, however those rows are still rendered and counted for pagination, so if there is a limit of 5 rows per page and all of them happen to have attribute `visible=false`, the page is blank.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to manage this thing on datasource/data set before assigning it to radgrid.

Comment: Is this the only way? We have different sets of data we want to display depending on the button user clicks and wanted to make just one call to the database. Is it possible?

Comment: Are you used needdatasource event to bind your radgrid?

Comment: We just specify DataSourceID.